# Getting a substring of an attribute in XPATH

Tags: string, xpath, substring

Given

```
<foo>
  <bar baz="Hello, World!">
</foo>
```

How do I all but the last 4 characters of @baz? One of my attempts was:

```
/foo/bar/@baz[substring( ., 0, -4 )]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Use**:

```
substring(/foo/bar/@baz, string-length(/foo/bar/@baz)-3)
```

Do note the `3` in the expression.

**The following is wrong**:

```
substring(/foo/bar/@baz, string-length(/foo/bar/@baz)-4)
```

because this returns the last 5 characters of the string value of the `baz` attribute.

Comment: @Volkirith, The phrase in the question "How do I all but the last 4 characters" is ambiguous -- maybe it meant "How do I **skip**  all but the last 4 characters" in which case the answer is correct. We can't know for sure, but the fact that the answer was accepted kinda confirms this guess. Of course, had it been the other way around (the meaning you suggest in your comment). the solution is easy enough: `substring(/foo/bar/@baz, 1, string-length(/foo/bar/@baz)-3)` Do note that recently moderators and other people have been "correcting" questions -- leading to this mess :(

Answer (score 8):

try this:
`substring-before(/foo/bar/@baz,"rld!")`

Answer (score 4):

That's actually not so bad, but IIRC substring doesn't like negative indices. I tried

```
substring(/foo/bar/@baz, string-length(/foo/bar/@baz)-4)
```

Which gave me the expected result.