# Using a XPATH substring function

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I need help figuring out this XPATH substring function, which I cannot get to work.  I have tried all kinds of variations of this:

```
.//a[contains(text(),'Home')]/@href[substring('jsessionid',12)]
```

Trying to get the jsessionid value from this tag:

```
<a href="/myapp/home;jsessionid=521EFCEE442922CF84C0FCC2809EC143">Home</a>
```

Nothing I try works.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322013/getting-a-substring-of-an-attribute-in-xpath), you can get the `jsessionid` from the 24th index of the @href attribute like this:

```
substring(//a[contains(text(),'Home')]/@href, 24)
```

[Example](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/68cf1b504c6d93c2c975e387b7788c5f)

Answer (score 0):

XPAth Extractor has known constraing of a lot of memory consumption due to building DOM tree in memory.

I believe that it can be handled much easier using [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar).

1. Add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` property to *user.properties* file which lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation
2. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan.
3. Wherever you require appending JSESSIONID cookie value to url use the following construction:

   ```
   /myapp/home;jsessionid=${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}
   ```