# How do I use the XPath substring function in the Chrome inspector?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath

How do I use the [XPath substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring) function in the Chrome inspector? I can't create a working example in the inspector's Elements tab.

For example, this selector:

```
//div[contains(text(),'Man')]
```

works on [this page](http://www.klgates.com/scott-r-bernhart), but

```
substring(//div[contains(text(),'Man')], 2)
```

fails to select anything. Shouldn't it continue to select the same element as the first selector?

Ultimately I'm passing the second selector to the JavaScript *document.evaluate()* function in order to get a piece of the *text()* string. As of now *document.evaluate()* is not returning anything for the second selector.

PS. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194421/using-a-xpath-substring-function) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322013/getting-a-substring-of-an-attribute-in-xpath) one but they don't mention using the Chrome inspector.

Comment: I've tried `document.evaluate("substring(//div[contains(text(),'Man')], 2)", document)`. Works fine, returns `XPathResult {resultType: 2, stringValue: "Managing Partner, Fort Worth Office↵↵", invalidIteratorState: false}`

Comment: What about in the Chrome inspector?

Comment: Yea, in inspector(Ctrl+F) does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that in Chrome inspector (using search within DOM - *Elements* tab) you can't highlight the text only or part of it.

For example, if you try `//div[contains(text(),'Man')]/text()`, you'll get the whole div element highlighted.

[image]

This may explain why `substring(//div[contains(text(),'Man')], 2)` doesn't work. Sadly, I can't find info about this in documentation.

So, as the alternative you can use [`$x(path)`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#xpath) or [`Document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) in Console.
For example,
`$x("substring(//div[contains(text(),'Man')], 2)")`
or
`document.evaluate("substring(//div[contains(text(),'Man')], 2)", document)`

Comment: Thanks but neither one these returns the partial string, so they are not a solution. The result should be _naging Partner, Fort Worth Office_. The first two chars, _Ma_, should have been removed by substring().

Comment: That's because text inside `div` is *"↵Managing Partner, Fort Worth Office↵↵"*. So, *substring* from position *2* returns *"Managing Partner, Fort Worth Office↵↵""*.

Comment: You can eliminate leading and trailing white-spaces by `normalize-space`. So to get *"naging Partner, Fort Worth Office"* - you'll use `substring(normalize-space(//div[contains(text(),'Man')]), 3)`

Comment: Thanks. It works so you have answered my question. I just wish I could get this to work in Node.js. The [doc.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) function does not return a match.

Comment: I don't know what do you use in nodejs, but you can use *evaluate* function in [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) or just use [package specifically for xpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath).