# XPath 2.0 return first string in an element node

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

ich want to return just Bangkok and nothing more, how can i select just the first string? There has to be a function or something like that?

the element node looks like this:

```
<Route>Bangkok 05.00, Puket 06.30
      <Ziel>Melbourne an 21.30</Ziel> 
</Route>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you do any research about this? Please, take a few moments to read [how to ask useful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sure i did research, but i can't find anything which just selects the first string. so if you have an idea, i would be really thankful

Comment: my XPath Query looks like this:
for $a in //Ereignis/Abflug return ($a/Flugnr, $a/Route/text())

but IDK how i just get bangkok

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322013/getting-a-substring-of-an-attribute-in-xpath

Comment: yeah i saw it with substring-before. But the problem with this function is, that i don't know what is behind Bangkok or another city! The tokenize function works better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tokenize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) in XPath 2.0 to split text by space and return only the first tokenize result:

```
//Route/tokenize(., ' ')[1]
```

Or if the target text is always in the first text node child of `Route` then the following should be slightly more efficient :

```
//Route/tokenize(text(), ' ')[1]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/yjn6aA3O2)</kbd>**

Adapted based on your attempted query :

```
for $a in //Ereignis/Abflug 
return ($a/Flugnr, $a/Route/tokenize(text(), ' ')[1])
```

Comment: hey, thanks for that! I didn't recognize that tokenize is for that... So i tried it, and my programm tells me this error: "Expecting a Node but found an Atomic Value instead: 'Bangkok'"

It has the right one, but doesn't return it?

Comment: It is likely related to the API of the XPath engine that you use. I don't know what your XPath engine is and how you use it, so the least I can suggest is to change the query to return uniform data type (probably change `$a/Flughr` to `$a/Flughr/string()`), if possible, and correct parameter that was explicitly mention about returning node, if any

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the first `text()` node can be achieved with

```
Route/text()[1]
```

And to only select 'Bangkok' you can use the `substring-before` XPath 1.0 function like this

```
substring-before(Route/text()[1],' ')
```